# 'Kinecter::getCloud' : this function cannot be compiled as managed, consider using #pragma unmanaged

Tags: c++, unmanaged, managed, point-cloud-library

*(The "Functon" is a compiler typo not mine :P)*

**my question,**

What I need to do, is get the pointcloud(XYZRGBA) data from pcl unmanaged C++, to C#.
I do this with the following code:

**Unmanaged.cpp (C++)**

```
float* getCloud(int clr_width, int clr_height, int dpth_width, 
int dpth_height, int frameId, int clr_focal_x, int clr_focal_y, 
int dpth_focal_x, int dpth_focal_y, unsigned char *image, 
unsigned char *depth_image) const
{
    (some implementation);
}
```

**END OF Unmanaged.cpp**

.

**Managed.cpp (C++)**

```
property float[]^ Receiver
{
    float[]^ get()
    {
        return gcnew float[]( Unmanaged->getCloud((int)clr_width, 
        (int)clr_height, (int)dpth_width, (int)dpth_height, (int)frameId, 
        (int)clr_focal_x, (int)clr_focal_y, (int)dpth_focal_x, 
        (int)dpth_focal_y, (unsigned char*)image, 
        (unsigned char*)depth_image) );
    }
}
```

**END OF Managed.cpp**

What I get is the error from the title:
'Kinecter::getCloud' : this functon cannot be compiled as managed, consider using #pragma unmanaged

Does someone know how to fix this?

Btw: The suggestion: #pragma unmanaged also doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, it turns out it had nothing to do with this bit of code -.-

it was the creation of the cloud which had trouble. 
(for PCL users)

```
cloud->sensor_origin_.setZero (); // BUGGY
cloud->sensor_orientation_.w () = 0.0;
cloud->sensor_orientation_.x () = 1.0;
cloud->sensor_orientation_.y () = 0.0;
cloud->sensor_orientation_.z () = 0.0;
return (cloud);
```

I guess I can't send a pointcloud unless I create a mirror version on C#.